# Exclusion does not work properly

Tags: plotting

See the code below  with the mentioned problem in the title.

```
f[x_]:=x^4-2x^3+2x-2;
g[x_]:=x^3-3x+2;
Plot[f[x]/g[x],{x,-2,6},
   PlotStyle->{Blue},
   Exclusions->{x^3-3x+2==0},
   ExclusionsStyle->{Red,Red},
   AspectRatio->Automatic]
```

Comment: Actually, `Exclusions` seems to work fine. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

### When the signs are the same

Because

```
Solve[{x^3 - 3 x + 2 == 0, -2 < x < 6}, x]
```

> `{{x -> 1}, {x -> 1}}`

and

```
Clear[f,g,h];
f[x_] = x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x - 2;
g[x_] = x^3 - 3 x + 2;
h[x]=f[x]/g[x];
Sign@Limit[h[x],x -> 1,Direction -> "FromBelow"]
Sign@Limit[h[x], x -> 1,Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `-1`
> `-1`

It means that the function `h[x]=f[x]/g[x]` have the same sign `-∞` and `-∞` (same direction) when `x->1-` and `x->1+`,so it cann't determint the infiniteline(need to use two points,but `-∞` and `-∞` are the same)

We have to add this infinite line manually.

```
Clear[f,g,h];
f[x_] = x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x - 2;
g[x_] = x^3 - 3 x + 2;
h[x]=f[x]/g[x];
Plot[h[x], {x, -2, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{1, 0}, {0, 1}]}]
```

[image]

### When the signs are not the same

We can also compare with

```
Clear[f, g, h];
f[x_] = x^4 - 2 x^3 + 2 x - 2;
g[x_] = (x - 1) (x^2 + 1);
h[x_] = f[x]/g[x];
Sign@Limit[h[x], x -> 1, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
Sign@Limit[h[x], x -> 1, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
Plot[h[x], {x, -2, 6}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Red]
```

> `-1`
> `1`

`-∞` and `∞` can determint a infiniteline, the `ExclusionsStyle` work.

[image]

and

```
{Plot[Tan[x], {x, -5, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[Abs@Tan[x], {x, -5, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Red]}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps WRI should add `ExclusionsStyle` spec for infinite singularities, no matter what the signs.

Comment: You can get the asymptote added semi-automatically with `Plot[{h[x], Cancel[h'[x] h[x]]}, {x, -2, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, None}, ExclusionsStyle -> {{Red, Red}}]`.